# XML parsing using Scala

Tags: scala, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file which I want to parse using Scala:

```
<infoFile xmlns="http://latest/nmc-omc/cmNrm.doc#info" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://latest/nmc-omc/cmNrm.doc#info schema\pmResultSchedule.xsd">
   <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="123456" operator="ABCD">
       <fileSender elementType="MSC UTLI"/>
       <infoCollec beginTime="2011-05-15T00:00:00-05:00"/>
   </fileHeader>

<infoCollecData>
    <infoMes infoMesID="551727">
        <mesPeriod duration="TT1234" endTime="2011-05-15T00:30:00-05:00"/>
        <mesrePeriod duration="TT1235"/>
        <mesTypes>5517271 5517272 5517273 5517274 </measTypes>
        <mesValue mesObj="RPC12/LMI_ANY:Label=BCR-1232_1111, ANY=1111">
           <mesResults>149 149 3 3 </mesResults>
        </mesValue>
    </infoMes>

    <infoMes infoMesID="551728">
        <mesTypes>6132413 6132414 6132415</mesTypes>
        <mesValue measObjLdn="RPC12/LMI_ANY:Label=BCR-1232_64446, CllID=64446">
            <mesResults>0 0 6</mesResults>
        </mesValue>
        <mesValue measObjLdn="RPC13/LMI_ANY:Label=BCR-1232_64447, CllID=64447">
            <mesResults>0 1 6</mesResults>
        </mesValue>
    </infoMes>

    <infoMes infoMesID="551729">
        <mesTypes>6132416 6132417 6132418 6132419</mesTypes>
        <mesValue measObjLdn="RPC12/LMI_ANY:Label=BCR-1232_64448, CllID=64448">
            <mesResults>1 4 6 8</mesResults>
        </mesValue>
        <mesValue measObjLdn="RPC13/LMI_ANY:Label=BCR-1232_64449, CllID=64449">
            <mesResults>1 2 4 5 </mesResults>
        </mesValue>
        <mesValue measObjLdn="RPC13/LMI_ANY:Label=BCR-1232_64450, CllID=64450">
            <mesResults>1 7 8 5 </mesResults>
        </mesValue>
    </infoMes>
</infoCollecData>
```

I want the file to be parsed as follows:

From the fileHeader I want to be able to extract operator name then to extract beginTime.

Next scenario ****extract the information which contains CllID then get its mesTypes and mesResults respectively ****

as the file contains number of  with different CllID so I want the final result like this

```
 CllID   date           time        mesTypes    mesResults 

64446   2011-05-15    00:00:00      6132413       0

64446   2011-05-15    00:00:00      6132414       0

64446   2011-05-15    00:00:00      6132415       6

64447   2011-05-15    00:00:00      6132413       0

64447   2011-05-15    00:00:00      6132414       1

64447   2011-05-15    00:00:00      6132415       6
```

How could I achieve this ? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import java.io._

import scala.xml.Node

object xml_parser {

  def main (args:Array[String]) = {
    val input_xmlFile = scala.xml.XML.loadFile("C:/Users/ss.xml")


    val fileHeader = input_xmlFile \ "fileHeader"
    val vendorName = input_xmlFile \ "fileHeader" \ "@operator"
    val dateTime = input_xmlFile \ "fileHeader" \  "infoCollec"   \"@beginTime"

    val date = dateTime.text.split("T")(0)
    val time = dateTime.text.split("T")(1).split("-")(0)

    val CcIds = (input_xmlFile \ "infoCollecData" \ "infoMes" \\ "mesTypes" )
    val cids = CcIds.text.split("\\s+").toList
    al CounterValues = (input_xmlFile  \ "infoCollecData" \\ "infoMes" \\ "mesValue" \\ "@meaObj")

    println(date);println(time);print(cids)
```

Comment: like wise i have lots of infomes which contains the mestypes, mesValue,mesResults. i am stuck here how i can apply If,Filter or any map function there.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest [kantan.xpath](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.xpath)? It seems like it should sort your problem rather easily.

Assuming your XML data is available in file `data`, you can write:

```
import kantan.xpath.implicits._

val xml = data.asUnsafeNode

// Date format to parse dates. Put in the right format.
// Note that this uses java.util.Date, you could also use the joda time module.
implicit val format = ???

// Extract the header data
xml.evalXPath[java.util.Date](xp"//fileheader/infocollec/@begintime")
xml.evalXPath[String](xp"//fileheader/@operator")

// Get the required infoMes nodes as a list, turn each one into whatever data type you need.
xml.evalXPath[List[Node]](xp"//infomes/mesvalue[contains(@measobjldn, 'CllID')]/..").map { node =>
    ...
}
```

Extracting the `CllID` bit is not terribly complicated with the right regular expression, you could either use the standard Scala `Regex` class or [kantan.regex](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.regex) for something a bit more type safe but that might be overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can implement what you want according to your xml format

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val inputFile = xml.XML.loadFile("C:/Users/ss.xml")
    val fileHeader = inputFile \ "fileHeader"
    val beginTime = fileHeader \"infoCollec"
    val res = beginTime.map(_.attribute("beginTime")).apply(0).get.text
    val dateTime = res.split("T")
    val date = dateTime(0)
    val time = dateTime(1).split("-").apply(0)

    val title = ("CllID", "date", "time", "mesTypes", "mesResults")
    println(s"${title._1}\t${title._2}\t\t${title._3}\t\t${title._4}\t${title._5}")

    val infoMesNodeList = (inputFile \\ "infoMes").filter{node => (node \ "mesValue").exists(_.attribute("measObjLdn").nonEmpty)}
    infoMesNodeList.foreach{ node =>
        val mesTypesList = (node \ "mesTypes").text.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
        (node \ "mesValue").foreach { node =>
            val mesResultsList = (node \ "mesResults").text.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
            val CllID = node.attribute("measObjLdn").get.text.split(",").apply(1).split("=").apply(1).toInt
            val res = (mesTypesList zip mesResultsList).map(item => (CllID, date, time, item._1, item._2))
            res.foreach(item => println(s"${item._1}\t${item._2}\t${item._3}\t${item._4}\t\t${item._5}"))
        }
   }
}
```

**Notes:** your xml file does not have the right format

1) miss close tag  in the last line of the file

2) line 11, have a wrong tag , which should be